# Prevent manual entry in Custom Date Picker

Tags: javascript, extjs, datepicker, sencha-architect

I have created a custom Date picker in ExtJs with only month and year field by referring to https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h5i&view/editor, but I am unable to disable the manual entry into the field. I want the input for that field to be given only by choosing in DatePicker. is there any attribute for doing so

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `editable:false` for avoiding manual entry.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Month', {
        format: 'F, Y',
        fieldLabel: 'Date',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        editable:false
    });
```

Is this what you were asking ?

Comment: adding this line allows to edit, Hope you have checked

Comment: Please check your fiddle by editable:false. I have checked in your fiddle and its working.